# Ajax javascript response in controller from form_for is rendered with the javascript as plain text

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, paperclip, form-for

I am trying to get a javascript response when I try to edit a user. I do this by issuing an ajax call when the form is submitted. The page that is rendered after the form is submitted is the plain text of the javascript response. So, the ajax isn't working correctly and the javascript is rendered as text.

Slim html:

```
= form_for @user, html: { multipart: true }, authenticity_token: true, :format => :js, remote: true do |form|
      = form.label :avatar
      = form.file_field :avatar
      = form.submit "add an avatar!"
```

update method in user controller:

```
 def update
     @user = User.find(params[:id])
     logger.debug request.format
     respond_to do |format|
          format.js { render layout: false, content_type: 'text/javascript' }
     end
  end
```

javascript response that is visible in plain text:

```
alert("hello");
```

Comment: I think there are issues with multipart and ajax.  Look into this further, you may need to find a work around.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately there is no easy and universal way to send multipart forms via ajax. But you can still solve the problem using this gem https://github.com/JangoSteve/remotipart.

Comment: when I remove :format => :js the request.format now prints text/html and I get a ActionController::UnknownFormat in UsersController#update

Comment: I get the same ActionController::UnknownFormat in UsersController#update error

Comment: logger.debug prints text/html

Comment: something might be wrong in your way. This shouldn't happen. Oh, you have attachment and multipart form.

Comment: That might solve the problem , but you're not indicating what is wrong with what I'm currently doing

Comment: Because when the form is multipart and contains html that is always consider as html request by rails form. And that is why you are always having html type request.

Comment: Now try to remove the attachment and multipart option you will get my direction working.

Comment: When I try to use this gem my server says "Rendered users/update.js.erb" but my alert("hello") is never being executed